# Dynamically load .xlsx files in ssis

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, script-task

I created an SSIS to load excel files. It loops through a specified folder for relevant files and reads the data in each file into a raw data table and then I have SQL scripts that does the validation and places the data in the relevant tables etc... and it all works fine.

but I now need make the ssis package handle loading excel files with 3 different file structures. ie one file will have 50 columns, one will have 55 and one will have 60.

I have tried using a script task to load the data

```
Insert into <rawdatatable> select * from openrowset('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','excel 8.0; database=D:\SSIS\FileToLoad.xlsx', 'Select * from [Sheet1$]')
```

but I keep getting the error below, but adding error logging doesn't give any other errors

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

[image]

I am using SQL Server 2014 and VS 2013

I'm not really sure what I am doing here, any help or guidance would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: That error isn't telling us anything. Add error handling to your Script task, and output the actual error. All that error effectively means is "An error occured."

Comment: You are using the connection string for .XLS and not .XLSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider, try following:

```
Insert into <rawdatatable> 
select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                         'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\SSIS\FileToLoad.xlsx;HDR=YES', 
                         'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

**References**

- [Import/Export Excel (.Xlsx) or (.Xls) File into SQL Server](http://www.ashishblog.com/importexport-excel-xlsx-or-xls-file-into-sql-server/)